# Basics of making a board game in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In a board game application, I tried the following code so that when a player's name is on two squares, it goes away from the previous square:

```
for (int e = 0; e < squares.length; e++) {
    //squares is an 
    //array containing all the labels that players 
    //play on  
    tmp = squares[e].getText();
    //this is supposed to be the text the squares       
    //originally had without 
    //any player's name 

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        //i = 6 because the die has 6 numbers. If a     
        //square 1-6 before another 
        //square has the player's name it should be removed from it. 
        if (squares[e].getText().equals(plyr1 + tmp)) {
            squares[e - i].getText().replaceAll(tmp + plyr1, tmp);                 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the players' names aren't removed from previous squares once they go on a square 1-6 places ahead. How should I solve it? Thank you.

I also don't know how to switch between players' turns. I have their names listed on the board. I want to, first of all, highlight a player's name when it's their turn, and, secondly, dehighlight it when their turn is over. I also want to change their score (each square on the board has a number that increases/decreases their points. How should I change the player's score depending on the number on the square?). When it's not a player's turn, their name on the board should stay stationary and the name of the player whose turn it is should move. For this, I need to start with all the players' names on the first label, "Start," and move their names according to whose turn it is. I do not know how to do this. Can anyone explain how to do any of this?

Comment: You need to fix your markup, your code is nearly unreadable right now.

Comment: What GUI library are you using? Swing?

Comment: Swing GUI - JFrame Form

Comment: The basics of making a Swing GUI is the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  First, you model your game, using one or more model classes.  Once you have the model, then you create the view.  Finally, you write controller code to update the model and repaint the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
squares[e-i].getText().replaceAll(tmp+plyr1,tmp);
```

String objects are immutable. You need to rewrite this as

```
squares[e-i].setText(squares[e-i].getText().replaceAll(tmp+plyr1,tmp));
```

**EDIT:** In your code, you're matching for a String

```
plyr1+tmp
```

But in the code, you're trying to replace

```
tmp+plyr1
```

This will never work unless tmp or plyr1 is defined as "". You need to verify that your logic is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but when I did that, the results were exactly the same. The only difference was that an error message that didn't affect the results went away.